# Laravel: variable in relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to insert a variable in a relationship Model?

I have a data structure where I have a main table and, linked to it, I have multiple translated records, in each language.

That is, I have a Content table for multiple records in the ContentLanguages ​​table.

Is it possible to carry out this relationship in Content table?

```
public function language($lang = 1)
{
    return $this->hasOne(AppInitLang::class)
        ->where('language_id', $lang);
}
```

If so, how do I send the $lang variable in eloquent?

Comment: You can use Laravel Morph Relation Model. 
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships
 Using this you can design the translation of the model. Even you can manage multiple tables data translation also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it exactly the way you are describing (i.e. as an eager load). Here are some options

If the $lang variable is chosen by the user and stored in his profile, you might be able to do something like this:

```
public function language()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AppInitLang::class)
        ->where('language_id', Auth::user()->lang);
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could also just make a function to return the language, but it won't be eager.

```
public function language($lang = 1)
{
    return AppInitLang::where('language_id', $lang)->where('id', $this->id)->first();
}
```